# Migration failed for upgrading data solution to VS2013

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, business-intelligence

When I try to open my DataSolution in VS2013, it tries to migrate it because I get the error

> These projects are either not supported or need project behavior imacting modifications to open in the version of Visual Studio.

I can then to a One-way upgrade which unfortunately fails with the error message

> The application which this project type is based on was not found. Visual Studio needs to make non-functional changes to this project in order to enable the project to open in Visual Studio 2013, Visual Studio 2012, and Visual Studio 2010 SP1 without impacting project behavior.

Has anyone encountered this error before and knows how to fix it?

Comment: Looks like you may need to dl the BI tool for VS2013. Here is a link: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42313

Comment: This helps? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16362244/visual-studio-2012-keeps-showing-upgrade-report